# Error after deleting Objective-C file Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode

I made an Objective-C file in my project and then found out I don't need now so I deleted it, but it is giving me the error

> error opening input file '/Volumes/MACHD3/XCODE
>   PROJECTS/learn2code/learn2code/learn2code-Bridging-Header.h' (No such
>   file or directory)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you deleted the bridging header when you deleted your Objective-C file? So if, make sure to go to your target's "Build Settings" and search for "bridging" and you'll see where this old bridging header is referenced. Remove this from your build settings, too.

[image: Remove Bridging Header Reference]